# Integral using partial fractions

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

I am having trouble using partial fractions to evaluate 
$$\int \frac{6x}{x^3-8} dx.$$  I can find the denominator but using equations to find the numerator is difficult.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry. I'm new to the format here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Partial fractions for: $\frac{6x}{x^3-8}$

$$\frac{6x}{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)}=\frac{C+Bx}{x^2+2x+4}+\frac{A}{x-2}$$

$$6x=A(x^2+2x+4)+(x-2)(C+Bx)$$

$$6x=4A-2C+(A+B)x^2+(2A-2B+C)x$$

$$\begin{cases}
4A-2C=0\\
2A-2B+C=6\\
A+B=0
\end{cases}$$

Solve

> $$\int \frac{6x}{x^3-8}dx$$

$$=6\int\frac{dx}{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)}\overset{\text{partial fractios}}{=}\int\frac{2-x}{x^2+2x+4}dx+\int\frac{dx}{x-2}$$

$$=-\frac 1 2\int\frac{2x+2}{x^2+2x+4}dx+3\int\frac{dx}{x^2+2x+4}+\int\frac{dx}{x-2}$$

Set $t=x^2+2x+4$ and $dt=(2x+2)dx$

$$=-\frac 1 2 \int \frac 1 t+3\int\frac{dx}{x^2+2x+4}+\ln|x-2|$$

$$\overset{\text{complete square}}{=}-\frac{\ln|t|}{2}+\ln|x-2|+3\int\frac{dx}{(x+1)^2+3}$$

$$=\color{red}{-\frac{\ln|x^2+2x+4|}{2}+\ln|x-2|+\sqrt 3\arctan\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt 3}\right)+\mathcal C}$$

Comment: Thank you for the full answer!

Comment: @MarcD. You're welcome

Answer (score 2):

We want to perform partial fraction of $\frac{6x}{x^3-8},$ therefore
$$\frac{6x}{x^3-8} = \frac{6x}{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)} = \frac{Ax+B}{x^2+2x+4} + \frac{C}{x-2},$$
hence
$$\frac{6x}{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)} = \frac{Ax^2-2Ax+Bx-2B+Cx^2+2Cx+4C}{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)} = \frac{(A+C)x^2+(-2A+B+2C)x+(4C-2B)}{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)},$$
and here is our system
$$
\begin{cases}
A+C = 0\\
2C+B-2A = 6\\
4C-2B=0
\end{cases},
$$
solving the system we obtain
$$
\begin{cases}
C = 1\\
B = 2\\
A=-1
\end{cases},
$$

can you do the integration, having $\frac{6x}{x^3-8} = \frac{2-x}{x^2+2x+4} + \frac{1}{x-2}?$

Comment: Yes, thank you I will be able to integrate after the partial fraction expansion.

Comment: Im so new that I cannot yet upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, factor $x^3-8$. $x^3-8=(x^2+2x+4)(x-2)$
$$\frac{6x}{x^3-8}=\frac{ax+b}{x^2+2x+4}+\frac{c}{x-2}$$
Then multiply the lhs denominator out on the right side:
$$6x=(x-2)(ax+b)+c(x^2+2x+4)$$
When $x=2$, $(x-2)(ax+b)$ vanishes and $$6(2)=c(4+4+4)\Rightarrow c=1$$
Now, we can use $c$ to solve for $ax+b$.
$$6x-(1)(x^2+2x+4)=(x-2)(ax+b)$$
which gives us $a=-1$ and $b=2$.
Thus $$\int\frac{6x}{x^3-8}dx=\int\frac{2-x}{x^2+2x+4}+\frac{1}{x-2}dx$$

Which gives you what echzhen just demonstrated.

Comment: This method is the one closest to the way my professor teaches it, while echzhens meathod is similar to the khan academy one which is also very helpful.  Thank you for your responses.

Comment: I think you must mean C=1

Comment: Yes, good catch

Comment: You also want $6x=(x−2)(ax+b)+\mathbf c(x^2+2x+4)$